# Null pointer on setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

I have an activity which leverages Navigation drawer and I have three fragment children attached in this. I have an Action Bar search implemented, while as everything is working fine on a 5.0 device, I am facing hiccups on a 4.0.3 device on one of the fragments. I am implementing search as follows:

```
SearchView searchView;

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu); 
        searchView = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);


        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText){

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)){

                    CursorAdapter filterAdapter = (CursorAdapter) Cur;
                    filterAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());
                    searchView.clearFocus();
                }
                else {
                    CursorAdapter filterAdapter = (CursorAdapter) Cur;
                    filterAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());
                }

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        Cur.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                return dbHelper.getSearchList(constraint);
            }
        });searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater); 
    }
```

At the start the first fragment works fine, when I use the Navigation drawer to select a different fragment my app crashes, here is the log cat:

```
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at com.exa.FragmentTab2.onCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentTab2.java:4477)
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:1871)
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2489)
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:395)
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:760)
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2607)
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.invalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:1950)
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at android.app.Fragment.setHasOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:901)
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at com.exa.FragmentTab2.onCreateView(FragmentTab2.java:298)
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5000)
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
11-25 17:00:17.554: E/AndroidRuntime(6667):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

in OnCreate the log refers to this statement:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

in the onCreateOptionsMenu the log refers to:

```
Cur.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider()
```

I am very sure that my Cursor is not null.

### EDIT

I removed the

```
  Cur.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                return dbHelper.getSearchList(constraint);
            }
        });
```

to onCreate and now I am getting a null pointer at:

`filterAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());`

Comment: highlight the 901 line plz..

Comment: 901 line is from the jar used

Comment: This: `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am very sure that my Cursor is not null.

I am even more sure that you are incorrect. The only way to get a `NullPointerException` on that line is if `Cur` is `null`.

Please move your `setFilterQueryProvider()` to a better place, such as where you assign `Cur` a value. Note that your `setFilterQueryProvider()` does not need to be in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, as it has nothing to do with `onCreateOptionsMenu()` (e.g., it does not need the `Menu` or `MenuInflater` objects).

Comment: I am assigning the value to Cur in every lifecycle method: `Cursor mCur;

 public void setList(){ 

  // String primaryId = null;
  dbHelper.open(); 
  String stat = fetch();
  mCur = dbHelper.magicSPQuery(stat); 
  Cur = new CurAdapter(getActivity(), mCur,0);   
  lv.setAdapter(Cur); 
 }` I call setup() in onStart, onCreate, onResume. I will try to analyze more and report back!

Comment: @user2822178: Do not do database I/O on the main application thread, please.

Comment: I had done that just to check if my Cur is null anywhere Once I remove this error I will place all items at proper places.

Comment: Edited my question, I did as you advised.

Comment: Eureka, its solved. It was trying to search on a Null value! I removed code from the if condition. Thanks a ton mate :)